# How to create a responsive table in NextJs when the table data comes from Contentful rich text?

Tags: next.js, html-table, responsive-design, contentful

I have a component in my NextJs project that takes an array of data from Contentful using Contentful Rich Text fields, each index in the array is a different HTML component. The way to render the data from contentful to display the html is to use `documentToReactComponents(content, renderOptions) from @contentful/rich-text-react-renderer`. The functionality I want to achieve is, when the screen size is reduced, I want the last column of data to be removed and appended to a new row. How can I achieve this? I am thinking there has to be a way to use a useEffect, grab the data in the column, then insert it into a new row.

I have a constant set like this:

```
  const renderOptions = {
  renderNode: {
    'table': (node: any, children: any) => <table className={`${styles.table}`}>{children}</table>
  }
};
```

Then I have custom CSS being imported that looks like this:

```
 .table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  resize:both;
}

.table th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```